# wcf concurrency mode=Multiple

Tags: wcf, session, concurrency

I am a beginner on state/concurrency management in WCF. Let's say I have a service class like below:

```
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
        public class Service1 : IService1
        {
            private int _myCounter;
            private MyType _myType;
            private static MyType _myTypeStatic;
            private static Dictionary<string,string> _d = new Dictionary<string,string>();


            public void Method1()
            {
                // logic to set _myType
                // logic to set _myCounter

                // logic to set _myTypeStatic
                // logic to set _d

            }
            public void Method2()
            {
                // logic to save _myType, set in Method1() to db
                // logic to save _myCounter, set in Method1() to db

                // logic to save _myTypeStatic, set in Method1() to db
                // logic to save _d, set in Method1() to db    
            }
        }
```

If 2 clients connect consume this service at the sametime, they will be running on 2 different threads. How will the state of 2 global class level variables change in this scenario as there is only instance of the service? How will it work for static variables and types? Is it possible that  these 2 threads have 2 different copies of variables data, but still working with one service instance?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps define a class or struct to store the variables set, then simply pass it in the method?

```
public class Storage
{
    public Storage(int myCounter, MyType myType)
    {
        _myCounter = myCounter;
        _myType = myType;
    }
    public int _myCounter;
    public MyType _myType;
}

...

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public void Method1(Storage st)
    {
        // logic to set _myType
        // logic to set _myCounter
    }
    public void Method2(Storage st)
    {
        // logic to save _myType, set in Method1() to db
        // logic to save _myCounter, set in Method1() to db
    }
}
```

This way the Service1 works on data it's not directly connected to - every caller will however have to "take care" of it's data, e.g. preserve Storage st somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

First, all the variables should be thread safe with critical sections. The static variables will be shared across all the instances even if you do not set the InstanceContextMode.Single. The class variables will be shared for all the threads entering into that instance. The ConcurrencyMode.Multiple indicates that multiple threads can enter. Further even if you apply critical sections then also the logic you are using will not work. If then thread sets the data and return releasing the critical section. Before it tries to make another call to save the data, another thread can override the data. This means you need to store the data in one operation. Or you want to set the data for some time and then store it then the way to go would be to store the data in a hash table. Like in method1, use critical section to set the data and put a unique key to set key for the data like client ID and return the key to the client if he is not aware of that. Then in method 2 the client will pass the key. Using the key access the hash table and retrive the data using the client and save it.